# Reducer is not a function. React Native Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to add a reducer to my react native app.
Here is the store constant:

```
export const USER_PROFILE = 'USER_PROFILE';
```

Here is the action.js

```
import {USER_PROFILE} from '../constants/index';

export function userProfile(userReducer) {
  return {
    type: USER_PROFILE,
    payload: {
      email: '',
    },
  };
}
```

This the userReducer that is causing the error. I keep getting an error of customerReducer is not a function.

```
import {USER_PROFILE} from '../constants/index';

const initialState = {
  userProfile: '',
};

const customerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        userProfile: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default customerReducer;
```

And I have declared the email as a state... `const [email, setEmail] useState('')`

calling the reducer here. `const customerReducer = useSelector(state => state.userProfile);`
Now dispatching it with the useDispatch method.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
...
dispatch(customerReducer(email));
```

Comment: Looks like you use reducer function not how it should be. Check https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started for more information.

Comment: You should dispatch action NOT reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action.js should look somthing like this:

```
import {USER_PROFILE} from '../constants/index';

export function userProfile(userReducer) {
  return {
    type: USER_PROFILE,
    payload: {
      email: userReducer.email,
    },
  };
```

and when you dispatch you should use the action "userProfile" not the reducer "customerReducer". Your dispatch should look somthing like this:

```
dispatch(userProfile({email}));
```

make sure to use curly brackets. beacause you should pass an object not a string.

Comment: Thank you that solved it....